# How do I link the static Stasm library to my program?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, cmake

Earlier I succesfully compiled Stasm using cmake on Ubuntu 13.10. It gave me the static library libstasm.a.
However, I'm trying to build my own program using Stasm code but every time I try g++ gives me this:

```
hanna@hanna-HP-650-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop$ g++ -Wall -L/home/hanna/Downloads/stasm4.1.0/build -lstasm stasmtest.cpp -o stasmtest
stasmtest.cpp:7:23: fatal error: stasm_lib.h: No such file or directory
#include "stasm_lib.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

I tried compiling the Minimal.cpp example in the external library because that is supposed to show how to use Stasm in my own programs but still I get the same error.

Can someone please tell me what command I should use to link the Stasm library to my program?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fritzone's answer gave me some progress. I added the -I and -L flags. However, then I got 'undefined reference to 'stasm_search_single' and other library functions. Turned out I put the flags in the wrong order.
For anyone interested, my code compiles using this command:
`g++ file.cpp -Wall -I/direction/to/includes -L/direction/to/libraries -lstasm -o file `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` (including the pkg-config part, code formatting is off)

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be: `g++ file.cpp -Wall -I/direction/to/includes -L/direction/to/libraries -lstasm -o file \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a compilation error, not a linking one. g++ cannot find the "stasm_lib.h" header. Use `-I/path/to/stasm_lib.h` as parameter to g++.